# How convert the ListActivity to a FragmentActivity in Android

Tags: java, xml, android-fragments

I am new to android I have a problem with the code below, is the Activity extends `ListActivity` with an RSS to show a `FragmentActivity` with `TabsHost`. I wish someone would help me convert the ListActivity to display in the `FragmentActvity` (say `ListActivity`) to convert `FragmentActivity`.

```
public class RssReaderActivity extends ListActivity { 
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> itemlist = null;
    private RSSListAdaptor rssadaptor = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
        itemlist = new ArrayList<RSSItem>(); 
        new RetrieveRSSFeeds().execute(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: public class RssReaderActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ArrayList<RSSItem> itemlist = null;
    private RSSListAdaptor rssadaptor = null;
    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    itemlist = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    
    new RetrieveRSSFeeds().execute();
}

Comment: Use FragmentActivity with ListFragment.

Comment: Don't comment code @AntonioGil. Just edit your post and include it.

Comment: something like this? FragmentActivity extends ListFragment

Comment: something like this? FragmentActivity extends ListFragment I would like an example that I can transform my East and ListActivity in Fragment